# Resource will not be loaded from every plugin in a multiple plugin application

Tags: c++, qt, plugins

I have an application which is basically a plugin manager. This application should be able to deal with an arbitrary numbers of plugins which have the same interface but can behave differently.

To achieve this, the plugins have this class hierarchy:

[image]

In this minimal example each plugin has just two methods: `getName` which returns a hardcoded string and `geId` which returns a string stored in a text file which will be compiled into a resource file of each plugin.

The thing is: each plugin returns its hardcoded name. But the returned Id is the Id of the **first** plugin in **both** cases (see output).

Why is that? This is the code and the application output:

**Application output**

```
############# Plugin load ok #############
"Plugin01"
"p01"

############# Plugin load ok #############
"Plugin02"
"p01"
############# ready #############
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QDir dir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());

    foreach(QString fileName, dir.entryList(QDir::Files))
    {
        QPluginLoader pluginLoader(dir.absoluteFilePath(fileName));
        QObject *plugin = pluginLoader.instance();
        if(plugin)
        {
            qDebug() << endl << "############# Plugin load ok #############";
            if(dynamic_cast<IPlugin* >(plugin))
            {
                qDebug() << dynamic_cast<IPlugin* >(plugin)->getName();
                qDebug() << dynamic_cast<IPlugin* >(plugin)->getId();
            }
        }
    }

    qDebug() << "############# ready #############";
    return a.exec();
}
```

**IPlugin.h**

```
class IPlugin : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        IPlugin(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
        virtual ~IPlugin() {}
        virtual QString getId() = 0;
        virtual QString getName() = 0;
};
```

**IPlugin01.h**

```
class IPlugin01 : public IPlugin
{
    public:
        IPlugin01(QObject *parent) : IPlugin(parent) {}
        virtual ~IPlugin01() {}
};

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(IPlugin01,
                    "Plugin01/0.1");
QT_END_NAMESPACE
```

**Plugin01.h**

```
class Plugin01 : public IPlugin01
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "Plugin01/0.1")
    Q_INTERFACES(IPlugin01)

    public:
        Plugin01(QObject *parent = 0);
        virtual QString getId();
        virtual QString getName();
};
```

**Plugin01.cpp**

```
Plugin01::Plugin01(QObject *parent) :
    IPlugin01(parent)
{

}

QString Plugin01::getId()
{
    QFile file(":/id.txt");

    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        return file.readAll();
    }

    return "";
}

QString Plugin01::getName()
{
    return "Plugin01";
}
```

**id.txt of Plugin01's resource file**

```
p01
```

**IPlugin02.h**

```
class IPlugin02 : public IPlugin
{
    public:
        IPlugin02(QObject *parent) : IPlugin(parent) {}
        virtual ~IPlugin02() {}
};

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(IPlugin02,
                    "Plugin02/0.1");
QT_END_NAMESPACE
```

**Plugin02.h**

```
class Plugin02 : public IPlugin02
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "Plugin02/0.1")
    Q_INTERFACES(IPlugin02)

    public:
        Plugin02(QObject *parent = 0);
        virtual QString getId();
        virtual QString getName();
};
```

**Plugin02.cpp**

```
Plugin02::Plugin02(QObject *parent) :
    IPlugin02(parent)
{

}

QString Plugin02::getId()
{
    QFile file(":/id.txt");

    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        return file.readAll();
    }

    return "";
}


QString Plugin02::getName()
{
    return "Plugin02";
}
```

**id.txt of Plugin02's resource file**

```
p02
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource path are "global", so, `:/id.txt` is incorrect. You should design your resource structure in other way. Or you should load resources manually.

Comment: Adding Plugin01 prefix in resource file of Plugin01 and Plugin02 prefix in resource file of Plugin02 solved the problem. Just curious: What do you mean by 'load resources manually'?

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible, but I think that Qt can load resources directly from binaries. See `QResource` class. I'm a bit confused, because I always use resources as external binary files, so it is possible to update rcc files without recompiling code (Command line is `rcc -binary myresource.qrc -o myresource.rcc`).